# How to extract text from Link in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following string:

`<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">StackOverFlow</a>`

How can I extract text (i.e. StackOverFlow) from the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No regex required:

```
var t_ = document.createElement('div'),
    a;
t_.innerHTML = htmlString; // <- string containing your HTML
a = t_.children[0];

var text = a.textContent || a.innerText; // W3C vs IE
```

Actually [parsing HTML with regular expressions is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Although it might be easy to come up with an expression for your specific case, it might not work well for a different string.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('link_id').innerHTML;
```

That was my solution before, user added more description but this is solution for current description

```
var s = '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">StackOverFlow</a>';
var text = s.match(/<a[^\b>]+>(.+)[\<]\/a>/)[1];
```

Comment: Can I use innerHTML on a string/var?

Comment: @user395881: No. Only DOM elements have that property.

Comment: your description was not as before, that's the reason I have received 2 down votes.

Comment: The question always was *How can I extract text (i.e. StackOverFlow) **from the string?*** I agree, the title can be misleading, but it's not the OP's fault that you got downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add an `id` to your link like so: `StackOverFlow" then you can get the text like this:

`document.getElementById('linkID').innerHTML;`

Comment: Ohh can't believe it took me this long to realise that! I thought the question referred to an actual link in the DOM.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right, having read and re-read the question about 10 times now! That plus the fact that the OP posted that comment about using `innerHTML` on a "string/var" on @Senad's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var text = '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">StackOverFlow</a>';
    var parser = null;
    if (window.DOMParser){
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
    } else{ // Internet Explorer
        xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async="false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(text); 
    }
    var a = xmlDoc.childNodes[0];
    alert(a.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp