# How to extract a link from a message with regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract text from Link in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345151/how-to-extract-text-from-link-in-javascript)

I want to extract a hyperlink in a message. I thought it should be done 
by regular expressions and then surrounded with a a-tag. 
But how to do a regular expression that extracts a link from a message?

Here's my incomplete attempt:

```js
var str = ' Disappointing Usability http://t.co/wkTFYhQq';
 var pattern = /http:///w{1,100}/i
 var str2 =  pattern.exec(str);
 alert(str2);
```

Comment: What problems are you having with your attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `match` with this regex, that should get you an array with all links in a string:

```
/(?:https?|ftp|www)[^\s]+/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern should capture the URL in a group:

```
var pattern = /(...)/;
var output = input.replace(pattern, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
```

There are heaps of URL patterns available, depending on how inclusive you want to be.